# OpenGL ES 2.0 SDK for Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, sdk, opengl-es

I would like to get started developing native (C/C++) OpenGL ES 2.0 applications for Windows Mobile (version 5 or later, any version would do, really). I do however have trouble finding appropriate headers and libraries.

What I am looking for is a OpenGL ES 2.0 SDK for Windows Mobile, or an SDK which contains the appropriate headers and libraries. Previously, when I have developed OpenGL ES 1.0 applications, I have used the headers and libraries provided by the Vincent3D open source OpenGL ES 1.0 software rendering project in order to compile my applications, but for 2.0 applications, I have found no such solution.

I have searched Microsoft's developer site, some phone manufacturers developer sites, Qualcomm's developer site, nVidia's developer site, etc. for an SDK, without any luck, however. I know there are OpenGL ES 2.0 applications out there so I guess there are SDKs available, I just need help finding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem there is no such SDK. Not publicly available anyhow. From what I gather, developers that have created GLES-applications for Windows Mobile has used the strategy suggested by Virne in one of the comments and created a lib from the GLES DLL.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Khronos OpenGL ES 2.0 SDK for Imagination POWERVR chips (SGX).](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES2xSGX.asp) It can be used to develop OpenGL ES 2.0 applications on PC. That's pretty handy. If you are targeting to some non-POWERVR chip, you can still use the SDK, but I have no idea if it helps at all when making actual Windows Mobile-build.

Comment: ATI/AMD has a similar solution which allows you to develop (and run) OpenGL ES 2.0 applications on desktop Windows. While it might be handy early in the development process, it really doesn't help when it comes to making and actual Windows Mobile build.

Comment: One solution might be to create lib-file yourself from DLL (opengles_cm.dll I think) that is in the device. Here's how: http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/ 

Headers should be same that come in PowerVR or ATI SDK's.